# Google Apps OpenID login for Django App

Tags: django, openid, google-apps, django-authentication

I have a django application built for an organization. But, all the users have accounts in the organization's google apps. We have been keeping two separate user accounts for them (google apps and the django app), which is not very neat. Their django username is the same as their google apps username (the part before `@domain.com`).

I want to simply change the login page of my django app so that redirects to google apps for authentication (ie, openid type login). Additionally, when they are logged in I would like it to return the User with the same username, so that way existing users are logged into their original accounts (since they have stuff saved under those accounts). And new users will just have a new django account created with that username.

Not sure if anyone is familiar with [googleappsauth](https://github.com/hudora/django-googleappsauth). Its a django module to allow openid login to a google apps domain. This seems perfect for me. But, its telling me I need an openid endpoint defined. The documentation does not seem to indicate that that is required, but I'm not very familiar with OpenID so I'm kind of stuck??

Answer (score 0):

`GOOGLE_OPENID_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud'`

Answer (score 0):

> To get the Google OpenID endpoint, perform discovery by sending either a GET or HEAD HTTP request to `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id.` When using a GET, we recommend setting the Accept header to `application/xrds+xml`. Google returns an XRDS document containing an OpenID provider endpoint URL.The endpoint address is annotated as:

```
<Service priority="0">
<Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server</Type>
<URI>{Google's login endpoint URI}</URI>
</Service>
```

from: [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#endpoint)

You can also use:

```
https://google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=<domain>
```

However, be aware that this causes some problems if you use python-openid. Patches [are available](https://github.com/adieu/python-openid).